# Torch: why convolution layer is even slower than full connect linear layer when in same data size

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, gpu, convolution, torch

I am implementing a neural-network to train mnist dataset with **torch7(LUA5.3)**, but I found 2 strange problems in torch:
**1.** Convolution layer is slower than full connected linear layer when in same data size.
**2.** Convolution layer is slower in GPU(TITAN X with cuda9.0) than in CPU

I do some simple experiments to prove that:
**For the first problem:**
(1) when batch size is 500 and feature dimensions is 784(28 * 28), for a full connected linear layer, input size is 500*784 and output size is 300(we set it to 300), it takes 1.67s to forward the data

[picture: 784 * 300 full connected linear layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNsSO.jpg)

(2) With the same batch size, convolution layer takes 3.07s, input2's size is 500*1*28*28, means 500 pictures with 1 channel and picture is 28*28. Convolution layer has 1 input plane and 3 output planes, kernel size is 2*2, step is 1, padding is 0

[picture: convolution layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpaQo.jpg)

**For the second problem:**
(1) With same data size and neural network structure, it takes even more time in GPU than in CPU:

[picture: It takes 11s in GPU however 3.07s in CPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aq3LE.jpg)

(2) Linear layer work well, it takes less time in GPU than in CPU indeed

[picture: it takes only 0.27s when running full connected linear layer in GPU](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijeOk.jpg)

However, it is obvious that convolution layer has less weights and need less computation, I think it should be much faster than linear layer. Moreover, GPU should not slower than CPU.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**For the first question**: the computation time does not only depend on the input data size. it also depends on the weights size, the number of operation between the weights and input data

**For the second question**:

(1)

It runs 11s on GPU(GeForce GTX TITAN X) and 14s on CPU(Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz) from my computer.

**for GPU, 11s**
[image: 11s on GPU]

**for CPU, 14s**
[image: 14s on CPU]

**GPU with nn.SpatialConvolutionMM, 8s**

It runs even faster if using nn.SpatialConvolutionMM.

[image: when using nn.SpatialConvolutionMM]

**The last thing**

The fewer weights do not mean less computation. When it comes to computation, it means the number of addition and multiplication.

**The reason why convolutional layer takes more time** added at 2018-01-11

The reason why convolutional layer takes more time than even if the computation complexity is lower than Linear regression. I found an explanation about how convolutional layers words [here](http://blog.csdn.net/shenxiaolu1984/article/details/52373174). The convolutional layer would duplicate the input data a lot so that the forward operation can be done by matrix multiplication, however, I do not perform any experiments yet. Can you try to implement convolutional operation with data duplication to validate the reason?

Comment: Sorry, may be I did not describe the question clearly. It is obvious that CNN needs less computation. For a linear layer, every forward process need 784*300 multiplication and 784*300 addition. For a convolutional layer, every feature map is 27*27[(28-2)/1+1 = 27], kernel size is 2*2, so it only needs 27*27*4 multiplication and 27*27*4 addition for each feature map, considering that there are 3 feature maps, the answer is 27*27*4*3 addition and multiplication. It is still far less than 784*300

Comment: feature map is 27*27 because (28-2)/1+1 = 27,2 is kernel width and the first 1 is step size

Comment: could you please run the same code on CPU again? And **make sure the CPU is at leisure**, I run the same code on CPU need only 3.x s, my cpu is Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5930K CPU @ 3.50GHz, 12 kernels. Though CPU is not powerful than GPU, 14s is still too long, 784 is not a large number, I think it should not take so much time

Comment: For the first question,  I agree with you. For the second question, it does not matter CPU vs GPU on small tasks. Anyway, GPU is much faster than CPU on the convolutional network.

Answer (score 0):

Though I do not know why it is very slow when run convolutional layer in GPU, I found a way to speed up it. 'cudnn' is a torch package built on NVIDIA CUDNN, which could speed up convolutional layer's computation greatly. See [here](https://github.com/soumith/cudnn.torch) for details. As I know, linear layer could not be speed up too much, however, convolutional layer's tell a different story